# Change colour of chapter number in a template called "harvard-thesis"

Tags: color, lettrine

Does anyone know how I can change the colour of the chapter number (or lettrine?) in the  `harvard-thesis` class file? It is Crimson at the moment, and I can't find where the colour is established in my template...

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{harvard-thesis}[2012/04/05 v0.4 Harvard University    Thesis Class]
\LoadClass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}


% Required packages
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
linktocpage,
colorlinks,
citecolor=cobalt,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
}

\RequirePackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
%\RequirePackage[numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[small, md, sc]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage[tight,nice]{units}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}

% colors
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
%\definecolor{Crimson}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Listing of figures}
%\raggedright

 \RequirePackage{pdfsync} %do pdf synchronization [andy]

\usepackage[closeFloats, noSeparatorLine]{fltpage} %use the custom    modified fltpage package
\RequirePackage{afterpage} 

\RequirePackage{lettrine} % big letter at start of chapter
\RequirePackage[width=6.4in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\normalfont\color{cobalt}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
 \pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\RequirePackage[]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\RequirePackage{titling}
\RequirePackage{setspace} 
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\RequirePackage[labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small},margin=0pt, ]{caption}
\doublespacing
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you pleas also add a minimal example of a document using the class and showing the issue?

Comment: The document class file loads the `pdfsync` package. Yikes!!! There are only two sensible reactions: (a) Don't use this document class, or (b) edit the class file so as not to load the `pdfsync` package. If you don't believe me, do feel free to search this site for postings related to `pdfsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you show uses the [`quotechap`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quotchap)package to achieve chapter titles with big chapter numbers. This package stores the color of the chapter number in `chaptergrey`. You can redefine this color by using a command like `\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0,1,0}` or any other valid color definition according to the [`color`](https://ctan.org/pkg/color) package in the preamble of your document to change the color of the chapter titles.

Comment: This worked!! thank you so much! And sorry for what now looks like a really easy thing to do!!

Comment: @AnaGonzalez: You're welcome. But please keep in mind the general remarks about the class file in Mico's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the chapter numbers is set by `chaptergrey` (as per the `quotchap` package). Do note that the actual default color is not grey but, instead, a dull red. (I wouldn't exactly call this dull color "crimson"...) Look for the `\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{.,.,.}` towards the end of the class file for the definition of the parameter.

Some additional comments about the class file. There's nothing about the LaTeX class file that would make me believe for a second that it actually formats theses according to the requirements of Harvard University. Note that anyone in the world can call the file `harvard-thesis.cls`; doing so does not make it a Harvard-related document! My main advice is simple: Don't use this class file -- unless you're fully prepared to endure lots of frustrations and are ready to waste lots of your precious time. The class file loads packages that should no longer be used under any circumstance whatsoever (e.g., `pdfsync`), it loads some packages that are deprecated (e.g., `units`), it loads packages even though there's no (valid) reason for loading them (e.g., it loads both `color` and `xcolor`), it leaves important parameters underspecified (e.g., take a look at how the `geometry` package is loaded), and it loads other packages at the wrong time (e.g., `hyperref`). In short, it's a mess. You've been warned.